# Чтение, фильтровка мусора и вывод в другой файл в bash

Tags: grep, файлы, bash

Добрый день! имеются логи которые надо привести в человеческий вид, удобоваримые для чтения.... первый этап осилил... отфильтровал не нужный мусор... на втором этапе застрял надо сделать так чтобы читало из файла 1 искало в файле 2 значение файла 1 первое вхождение (остальные не интересуют) и писало результат в файл 3

Comment: Странная постановка задачи. Без конкретизации можно получить крайне неэффективное решение.

Comment: sercxjo, KoVadim cпасибо за ответы привел к более удобоваримому виду часть лога, но столкнулся с проблеммой file1 -список пользователей, file2 -кусок текущего лога, и команда grep завершается с ошибкой не найдя пользователя в логе

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh
read i < file1
grep -m1 "$i" < file2 > file3
```

Answer (score 0):

может просто на python/perl/любимый скриптовый язык написать? будет точно проще. А в большинстве линукс/bsd дистрибутивов python или perl есть с вероятностью 99.9%.

Но если нужно делать замену, то тогда это путь к awk или sed. Если замен много, то можно пройтись по файлу несколько раз (долго, но...)